# React ActionCable Provider createConsumer function not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, actioncable

I am building an application and decided to utilize ActionCable for websockets. My goal is to keep track of each user in Actioncable so when they unsubscribe/close the window, I can remove them from a running list. There is no issue when the users join and I push them into the list; however, I cannot seem to establish a connection that allows me to set up the current_user attribute. Here is the error that is displaying. 
[ActionCable createConsumer is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3U42.png)

Here is the code where I am trying to implement it.

```
import { ActionCableProvider, ActionCable } from 'react-actioncable-provider'
import App from '../App'

import React from 'react';

const cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable')
export default function Container (props) {
    return (
        <ActionCableProvider cable={cable}>
            <App />
        </ActionCableProvider>
    )
}
```

My Backend looks like this. 
//app/channels/lobbies_channel.rb

```
 class LobbiesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed
    @lobby = Lobby.find(params[:lobby_id])
    stream_for @lobby
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Here is my connection.rb file, which I have not built out yet because it is not being triggered or reaching the byebug.

```
 module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user
  end

  def connect
    byebug
    self.current_user = find_verified_user
  end

  private

  def find_verified_user
    byebug
  end
end
```

//routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :lobbies, only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  post '/available' => 'lobbies#checkAvail'
  post '/joinlobby' => 'lobbies#joinLobby'
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

Can anyone help me set up my action cable provider so it triggers the connection file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `ActionCable` from the `actioncable` package. If you look, the `ActionCable` that `react-actioncable-provider` exports is actually a React component, not the library:

```
import ActionCable from 'actioncable'
import ActionCableProvider from 'react-actioncable-provider'
import App from '../App'
import React from 'react'

// ...
```